# How can i display a text on zedboard's oled display

Tags: fpga, zynq

I want to show text on OLED screen on zedboard. I have done a lot of research on the internet, but I could not get a result. I'm new on FPGA yet. Is there any resource that can help me and new ones like me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is literally one of the Xilinx starter example projects: "Basic Vivado IPI Design" on http://zedboard.org/support/design/1521/11. Account required:

```
The design consists of a Zynq subsystem and I added (3) single channel soft GPIO peripherals to interface to the:
 - 5 buttons
 - 8 switches
 - 8 LEDs
```

Comment: 8 LEDs is not exactly the OLED screen that's sitting on the 4-wire spi (cs/clk/mosi/dc#) and needs knowledge about its controller IC :)